# Why is only the last element added to list stored/printed in the following program in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

A Kotlin beginner here. Why is it that only the last element of my list printed when I loop through the list? My code is fairly straightforward.

```
class Person {

    var personName:String = "Guest"
    var personAge:Int = 20
    var personHobby:String = "Default"
}

fun main()
{
    val obj = Person()
    val listofPeople = mutableListOf<Person>()
    val namesList = arrayOf("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
    val hobbyList = arrayOf("Swimming", "Reading","Music")


    for (loop in 0..2) {
        obj.personName = namesList[loop%3]
        obj.personHobby = hobbyList[loop%3]
        obj.personAge = loop * 20
        listofPeople.add(obj)
    }
    println("The size of the list is: ${listofPeople.size}")
    println("The details are:")
    for (person in listofPeople)
        println("Name: ${person.personName}, Age: ${person.personAge}, Hobby: ${person.personHobby}")

}
```

The output after running the above code is:

```
The size of the list is: 3
The details are:
Name: GHI, Age: 40, Hobby: Music
Name: GHI, Age: 40, Hobby: Music
Name: GHI, Age: 40, Hobby: Music
```

I am confused about what is happening here, is the obj not added each time the loop runs? Or, adding the object to the list happens after the loop executes and only the last element is added to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you reuse `Person` object within a loop and your result list consists of multiple references to the same object. To make it work you should move `val obj = Person()` inside the loop:

```
for (loop in 0..2) {
    val obj = Person()
    obj.personName = namesList[loop%3]
    obj.personHobby = hobbyList[loop%3]
    obj.personAge = loop * 20
    listofPeople.add(obj)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood it after some time I posted the above code.